# How to disable X Window on startup

Tags: fedora

How do I disable X Window system on Fedora 11 box from startup at boot time ? Since host is used as a server and not as a desktop I'd like not to waste limited memory resources on X and Gnome.

Answer (score 10):

The /etc/inittab file describes which processes are started at bootup and during normal operation. This file is used to start X windows system at boot by setting default run level to 5. Edit the file /etc/inittab using a text editor such as vi, enter:

vi /etc/inittab

Find line:

```
id:5:initdefault:
```

Replace with:

`id:3:initdefault:`

Save and close the file. Restart the server.

You can also drop to text mode by typing init command:

```
init 3
```

You should then be able to still run the command (if you need X)

```
startx
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove an init script symlink from '/etc/rc?.d/': it should be called 'S*-gdm'. You can also rename it from 'S*' to 'K*'. The '?' sign stands for a runlevel.